# how to make circle in matlab and generate random points inside it

Tags: matlab, random, geometry, point

[image]hello i want to ask a question how to make a circle in matlab and mark its center and generate a certain number of random points inside it for example 50 ? i know this code to make a circle

```
x = linspace(-sqrt(10),sqrt(10));
y1 = sqrt(10-x.^2);
y2 = -sqrt(10-x.^2);
plot(x,y1,x,y2)
axis equal
hold on
```

but i don't know how to generate 50 random points inside it 
then i thought of this pseudo code but i don't know how to write it in matlab

```
01: FOR all nodes j
 02: FOR all nodes i except node j 
03: IF distance(j to center) < distance(j to  i) AND
 04: distance(i to cell center) < distance(j to  i) 
05: THEN there's a red link from node i to node j 
06: ELSEIF distance(j to cell center) < distance(j to  i)
 07: THEN there's a blue link from node i to node j 
08: ELSE there's no D2D link from node i and j;
 09: node i has a green link with the base station 
10: END if 
11: END inner for-loop
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. The peudo-code defines a link set on a defined set of nodes, it does not generate a random set of nodes.

Comment: Do you want the points to be uniformly distributed in the circle?

Comment: just an aside, you can generate random points in a square that contains the circle and choose only those of fall in the circle...

Comment: i want it like the picture in my post i uploaded it now

Answer (score 5):

Think this is what you need -

```
%%// Plot the circle
x = linspace(-sqrt(10),sqrt(10));
y1 = sqrt(10-x.^2);
y2 = -sqrt(10-x.^2);
plot(x,y1,x,y2)
axis equal

%%// Choose from 1000 random point pairs
N = 1000; 
%%// Radius of circle
radius = sqrt(10); 

%%// Create a random point matrix Nx2
points_mat = [ radius*2*(rand(N,1)-0.5) radius*2*(rand(N,1)-0.5)];

%%// Select the first 50 pairs that lies inside circle
ind1 = find(sqrt( points_mat(:,1).^2 + points_mat(:,2).^2 )<radius);
points_mat=points_mat(ind1(1:50),:);

%%// Plot the 50 points on the circle
hold on
text(0,0,'x Center') %%// Center
text(points_mat(:,1),points_mat(:,2),'o') %%// 50 points
```

**Plot**

[image]

Comment: thank u so much,so do you know after this how can i measure the distance between every point in the circle and the rest of the points and every point and the center like this pseudo code 01: FOR all nodes j
 02: FOR all nodes i except node j 
03: IF distance(j to center) < distance(j to  i) AND
 04: distance(i to cell center) < distance(j to  i) 
05: THEN there's a red link from node i to node j 
06: ELSEIF distance(j to cell center) < distance(j to  i)
 07: THEN there's a blue link from node i to node j 
08: else node i has a green link with the center 
09: END if 
10: END inner for-loop

Comment: Look into `pdist2`. It does exactly that. More info here - http://www.mathworks.in/help/stats/pdist2.html

Answer (score 4):

I don't know matlab, so I can't help you there, but if you want to do this without rejection you can generate the points in polar coordinates.  If `rand()` returns a Uniform(0,1) random number, then:

```
r = radius * sqrt(rand())
theta = 2 * Pi * rand()
x = r * cos(theta)
y = r * sin(theta)
```

will yield values which are uniformly distributed within a circle of radius `radius`.  Note the square root on the calculation of `r`, which adjusts the distribution of distance from the center of the circle so that the number of points at a given distance is always proportional to the area and hence is uniform. For spherical uniformity you'd take the cube root to keep proportionality to the volume, and in general the k<sup>th</sup> root for a k-dimensional hypersphere.

Comment: Those points will not be uniformly distribueted in the circle. Their radial and angular positions will be uniformly distributed, but since the area element is r*(dtheta)(dr) there is more area at a large radius so you need to choose more points at a large radius to end up with a uniform distribution in space. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837572/generate-a-random-point-within-a-circle-uniformly

Comment: I missed the `sqrt` in there, very sorry about that. My mistake. Unfortunately it looks like my downvote is locked now unless the posted is edited :( You might consider editing to add your additional explanation and I'll gladly switch to an upvote.

Comment: @DougLipinski Explanations are good, I should have put one in before so thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
%// Set parameters
R = 0.5;   %// radius
C = [3 4]; %// center [x y]
N = 50;    %// number of points inside circle

%// generate circle boundary
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
x = R*cos(t) + C(1);
y = R*sin(t) + C(2);

%// generate random points inside it
th = 2*pi*rand(N,1);
r  = R*rand(N,1);

xR = r.*cos(th) + C(1);
yR = r.*sin(th) + C(2);

%// Plot everything
figure(1), clf, hold on
plot(x,y,'b')
plot(C(1),C(2),'r.', 'MarkerSize', 100)
plot(xR,yR,'k.')
axis equal
```

[image]

Here's why that could be useful:

```
%// Set parameters
R = 0.5;     N = 50;
C = [3 4];   M = 100;  %// points on boundary

%// generate all points at once
t  = linspace(0, 2*pi, M)';
th = 2*pi*rand(N,1);
r  = R*rand(N,1);
xR = [R*ones(M,1); r] .* cos([t; th]) + C(1);
yR = [R*ones(M,1); r] .* sin([t; th]) + C(2);

%// Plot everything
figure(1), clf, hold on
plot(xR(1:M),yR(1:M),'b')                %// circle boundary
plot(C(1),C(2),'r.', 'MarkerSize', 100)  %// center
plot(xR(M+1:end),yR(M+1:end),'k.')       %// random points
axis equal
```

Comment: thank u so much,do you know after this how can i measure the distance between every point in the circle and the rest of the points and every point and the center like the pic above and pseudo code a 01: FOR all points j 02: FOR all points i except point j 03: IF distance(j to center) < distance(j to i) AND 04: distance(i to cell center) < distance(j to i) 05: THEN there's a red link from node i to node j 06: ELSEIF distance(j to cell center) < distance(j to i) 07: THEN there's a blue link from node i to node j 08: else node i has a green link with the center 09: END if 10: END inner for-loop