# Unity3d shotgun cone shoot

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raytracing

I'm using raycasts as a shotgun. I randomize direction of each ray:

```
Vector3 direction = new Vector3 (UnityEngine.Random.Range (-splash, splash), UnityEngine.Random.Range (-splash, splash), 100);
```

Everything works fine, but that maximum "range" of this direction is rectangle and I want an ellipse. It's hard to explain:
[image: Raycast]
It's seems I should use normalization somewhere, but I don't know where.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837572/generate-a-random-point-within-a-circle-uniformly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coordinates of points on circle can be calculated like this `x = r*cos(a), y = r*sin(a)`. If r is random points will be inside of circle with radius of "splash";

```
Vector3 direction = new Vector3( Random.Range(-splash,splash)*Mathf.Cos(Random.Range(0,2*Mathf.PI)),Random.Range(-splash,splash)*Mathf.Sin(Random.Range(0,2*Mathf.PI)),0 );
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about math :)

Comment: Unity has a function called Random.insideUnitSphere there is also Random.insideUnitCircle. Not sure if that helps your case... http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.html