# Is there any type-independent random generator for C++?

Tags: c++, templates, std, complex-numbers

I have a class, which stores and processes data of type `T`, which is just a template class name.

```
template<class T=float>
class myClass {
public:
    //...
};
```

Inside one of it's functions, I would like to generate random numbers, with a given maximum absolute value.

I started with:

```
T randvalue = ((T)rand() / RAND_MAX)*MAX_ABS
```

It works with float, and double. But I would like to make it work with complex numbers also. If a `double` is casted to `complex<double>`, then it will have only a real part. The imaginary part remains zero, so I can't generate complex numbers with imaginary part at the moment.

I don't ask for code, just give me hints, how to start. I would like to understand, how could I create a templated random generator.

Class `T` is a type, where `abs`, `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` are defined.

Comment: Just use two random numbers if the type is complex. And btw. C++ has templated random number generators, but I believe, they work only fforbuiltin types.

Comment: I would like to implement it without branches, if it is possible. The complex was just an example, why my code does not work in every cases.

Comment: You don't need branches - you can just specialize your template for complex numbers. You could of course write random bits to the memory address of your variable, but im not sure, if this will always result in leagle values.

Comment: Think also about the distribution you want to use. For example, do you want "uniformly distributed" is some region of the complex plane? If so, then just randomly generating the real and imag won't do the trick. Some more ideas here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837572/generate-a-random-point-within-a-circle-uniformly

Comment: The problem I see with *complex* numbers is how to define an interval? Normally you would ask for a random number *between* two different values. How is that supposed to work with complex numbers? Pythagoras? Or two separate intervals?  I think it is asking a lot for a templated random generator to cover unknown types in advance unless they closely mimicked built-in types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use overload:

with something like

```
template <typename T> struct tag {};
float create_random(tag<float>);
double create_random(tag<double>);
template<typename T>
complex<T> create_random(tag<complex<T>> c);
```

use

```
T randvalue = create_random(tag<T>{});
```

or template specialization:

```
template <typename T>
struct random_generator
{
    T operator()(); // you can provide default implementation.
};

template <> float random_generator<float>::operator()() {/**/}
template <> double random_generator<double>::operator()() {/**/}
template <typename T> complex<T> random_generator<complex<T>>::operator()() {/**/}
```

and use it

```
T randvalue = random_generator<T>(/**/)();
```

Note: you have better generator than `rand` in `<random>`