# Uniform sampling of intersection area of two disks

Tags: math, random, geometry

Given 2D uniform variable we can generate a uniform distribution in a unit-disk as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837572/generate-a-random-point-within-a-circle-uniformly).

My problem is similar in that i wish to uniformly sample the intersection area of two intersecting disks where one disk is always the unit-disk and the other can be freely moved and resized like [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iy8chljh2n)

[image]

I was trying to split the area into two regions (as depicted above) and sample each region individual based on the respected disk. My approach is based on uniform disk algorithm cited above. To sample the first region right of the center line I would restrict theta to be within the two intersection points. Next r would need to be projected based on that theta 
such that the points are pushed in the area between our mid line and the radius of the disk. The python sample code can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1686222).

```
u = unifrom2D()
A;B; // Intersection points
for p in allPoints
    theta = u.x * (getTheta(A) - getTheta(B)) + getTheta(B)
    r = sqrt(u.y + (1- u.y)*length2(lineIntersection(theta)))  
    p = (r * cos(theta), r * sin(theta))
```

However this approach is rather expensive and further fails to preserve uniformity. Just to clarify i do not want to use rejection sampling.

Comment: In theory, you could find the length of each line in the intersected area and integrate, creating a "probability distribution", and hope that it has an easy to compute inverse. However, I'd do w/ rejection sampling, even though I know you explicitly reject it.

Comment: Why don't you want to use rejection sampling?  If you use an appropriate bounding box to sample from, it will even be pretty efficient.

Comment: I want to use this method in ray-tracing to choose the lens-sample points based on the previously choosen image-sample-position, see [here](https://knork.org/realistic-bokeh.html). I am currently implementing this method in the blender-cycles-renderer, [here](https://developer.blender.org/D2922). Rejection sampling, as currently in use, leads to some regions of the image receiving fewer samples thus more noise. Further all samples are send to the gpu once, requesting new samples for rejected ones would thus be utterly complex and expensive.

Comment: @barrycarter my answer computes this "probability distribution" - and since angle and trigonometric function on it are mixed in it there is no analytic inverse. But the derivatives can be computed analytically, so numerically inverting can be done really fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is better than rejection sampling, but here is a solution for uniform sampling of a circle segment (with center angle <= pi) involving the numerical computation of an inverse function. (The uniform sampling of the intersection of two circles can then be composed of the sampling of segments, sectors and triangles - depending on how the intersection can be split into simpler figures.)

First we need to know how to generate a random value `Z` with given distribution `F`, i.e. we want

```
P(Z < x) = F(x)                   <=>  (x = F^-1(y))
P(Z < F^-1(y)) = F(F^-1(y)) = y   <=>  (F is monotonous)
P(F(Z) < y) = y
```

This means: if `Z` has the requested distribution `F`, then `F(Z)` is distributed uniformly. The other way round:

```
Z = F^-1(Y),
```

where `Y` is distributed uniformly in `[0,1]`, has the requested distribution.

If `F` is of the form

```
       / 0,                             x < a
F(x) = | (F0(x)-F0(a)) / (F0(b)-F0(a)), a <= x <= b
       \ 1,                             b < x
```

then we can choose a `Y0` uniformly in `[F(a),F(b)]` and set `Z = F0^-1(Y0)`.

We choose to parametrize the segment by `(theta,r)`, where the center angle `theta` is measured from one segment side. When the segment's center angle is `alpha`, the area of the segment intersected with a sector of angle `theta` starting where the segment starts is (for the unit circle, `theta` in `[0,alpha/2]`)

```
F0_theta(theta) = 0.5*(theta - d*(s - d*tan(alpha/2-theta)))
```

[image]
where `s = AB/2 = sin(alpha/2)` and `d = dist(M,AB) = cos(alpha/2)` (the distance of the circle center to the segment). (The case `alpha/2 <= theta <= alpha` is symmetric and not considered here.)
We need a random `theta` with `P(theta < x) = F_theta(x)`. The inverse of `F_theta` cannot be computed symbolically - it must be determined by some optimization algorithm (e.g. Newton-Raphson).

Once `theta` is fixed we need a random radius `r` in the range

```
[r_min, 1], r_min = d/cos(alpha/2-theta).
```

For `x` in `[0, 1-r_min]` the distribution must be

```
F0_r(x) = (x+r_min)^2 - r_min^2 = x^2 + 2*x*r_min.
```

Here the inverse can be computed symbolically:

```
F0_r^-1(y) = -r_min + sqrt(r_min^2+y)
```

Here is an implementation in Python for proof of concept:

```
from math import sin,cos,tan,sqrt
from scipy.optimize import newton

# area of segment of unit circle
# alpha: center angle of segment (0 <= alpha <= pi)
def segmentArea(alpha):
  return 0.5*(alpha - sin(alpha))

# generate a function that gives the area of a segment of a unit circle
# intersected with a sector of given angle, where the sector starts at one end of the segment. 
# The returned function is valid for [0,alpha/2].
# For theta=alpha/2 the returned function gives half of the segment area.
# alpha: center angle of segment (0 <= alpha <= pi)
def segmentAreaByAngle_gen(alpha):
  alpha_2 = 0.5*alpha
  s,d = sin(alpha_2),cos(alpha_2)
  return lambda theta: 0.5*(theta - d*(s - d*tan(alpha_2-theta)))

# generate derivative function generated by segmentAreaByAngle_gen
def segmentAreaByAngleDeriv_gen(alpha):
  alpha_2 = 0.5*alpha
  d = cos(alpha_2)
  return lambda theta: (lambda dr = d/cos(alpha_2-theta): 0.5*(1 - dr*dr))()

# generate inverse of function generated by segmentAreaByAngle_gen
def segmentAreaByAngleInv_gen(alpha):
  x0 = sqrt(0.5*segmentArea(alpha)) # initial guess by approximating half of segment with right-angled triangle
  return lambda area: newton(lambda theta: segmentAreaByAngle_gen(alpha)(theta) - area, x0, segmentAreaByAngleDeriv_gen(alpha))

# for a segment of the unit circle in canonical position
# (i.e. symmetric to x-axis, on positive side of x-axis)
# generate uniformly distributed random point in upper half
def randomPointInSegmentHalf(alpha):
  FInv = segmentAreaByAngleInv_gen(alpha)
  areaRandom = random.uniform(0,0.5*segmentArea(alpha))
  thetaRandom = FInv(areaRandom)
  alpha_2 = 0.5*alpha
  d = cos(alpha_2)
  rMin = d/cos(alpha_2-thetaRandom)
  secAreaRandom = random.uniform(0, 1-rMin*rMin)
  rRandom = sqrt(rMin*rMin + secAreaRandom)
  return rRandom*cos(alpha_2-thetaRandom), rRandom*sin(alpha_2-thetaRandom)
```

The visualisation seems to verify uniform distribution (of the upper half of a segment with center angle `pi/2`):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
segmentPoints = [randomPointInSegmentHalf(pi/2) for _ in range(500)]
plot.scatter(*zip(*segmentPoints))
plot.show()
```

[image]

Comment: "The uniform sampling of the intersection of two circles can then be composed of the sampling of segments, sectors and triangles - depending on how the intersection can be split into simpler figures". I think that's the difficult part of this problem; generating a random segment inside a circle doesn't make the OP's problem easier.

Comment: @barrycarter Decomposing the intersection of two circles into two segments (one of each circle) and - if a segment contains the circle center - further decomposing a segment into a sector and a triangle is straight forward. (Alltogether there will be two segments or a segment of one circle, a sector ot the other circle and a triangle.) The corresponding areas A1, A2, ... can easily be computed. For sampling the whole intersection one can put a switch on top: Y = uniform(0, A1+A2+...); if (Y < A1) get sample point of region 1 else if (Y-A1 < A2) get sample point of region 2 ...

Comment: OK, I guess my question is: why not write code that solves the whole problem and then show a distribution that looks uniform on the intersection of two circles?

Comment: @barrycarter as the OP pointed out himself: sampling the segment is the crucial part he is actually interested in. You are welcome to fill in the rest.

Comment: It took me a while to actually understand what you did. One question remains though. We essentially use the area function as *CDF* which means it should integrate to 1 over the domain. Which means we would need to normalize F0_theta by dividing by half the total area of the circle segment. Further i realized that intersections where the center of the second disk is still inside the first like [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/utj400tmxi) would not be possible with the current approach. Non the less your post was very useful.

Comment: @Knork area (parametrized by angle) as CDF: sure. When you fix an angle `theta0`, you want `P(point is in area with theta < theta0)` = `area(theta0)/area(theta_max)`. So `area(theta0)/area(theta_max)` is the CDF.

Comment: @Knork Normalization is only necessary if you want to choose the uniformly distributed variable from `[0,1]`. For programming it is easier to omit normalization and choose the uniformly distributed variable from the appropriate interval (see my distinction between `F0` and `F`).

Comment: @Knork When the intersection contains both circle centers: in your example you can decompose the intersection into a segment of the red circle and a sector of the blue circle and the triangle between - where for all components it is known how to sample them uniformly (see my comment above answering barrycarter`s first question)