# Find evenly distributed random points on a spherical cap

Tags: algorithm, math, geo

I have a latitude, longitude and radius of 400m-1000m forming a [spherical cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap). I need to find a random point on that cap. The points must be evenly distributed over the area.

There is a related question about finding [random points in a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837572/generate-a-random-point-within-a-circle-uniformly). My first thought was to project the cap on to a Cartesian plane and using the circle algorithm. The radius is small enough that there should be no important level of error.

I'm not sure if projecting and then converting the point back to a lat/lng is the simplest solution or what other possible solutions there are to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate random azimuth in range 0..360 and random distance with sqrt-distribution to provide unifrom distribution

```
d = maxR * Sqrt(random(0..1))
theta = random(0..1) * 2 * Pi
```

Then get geopoint coordinates using bearing and distance as described [here](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) `(Destination point given distance and bearing from start point)`

```
φ2 = asin( sin φ1 ⋅ cos δ + cos φ1 ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos θ )
λ2 = λ1 + atan2( sin θ ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos φ1, cos δ − sin φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 )

where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, θ is the bearing
(clockwise from north), δ is the angular distance d/R; 
d being the distance travelled, R the earth’s radius
```

Comment: This seems good. I'm just trying to understand it all. So random in square root is more likely to pick higher values to make up for the fact that there is more space?

Comment: Yes. Ring area is proportional to squared radius, so to provide uniform filling we use inverse function [Mathworld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html)

Comment: Got this working and it works well. The only bit that caught me out is the second part accepts lat,lng in radians.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the wiki page `theta + phi = 90` if `phi` is a latitude. On the other hand, as `r` is fixed for all points on the cap, we just need set the value of the `theta`. Hence, you can pick a random value from `0` to `theta` value (related to the cap) and define the point by the explained constraints.

Answer (score 0):

For a disc very small compared to the radius of the sphere the lat-long projection will simply be approximately an ellipse except when you are very close to poles.

First compute the stretch at the given latitude:

```
double k = cos(latitude * PI / 180);
```

then compute the disc radius in latitude degrees

```
// A latitude arc-second is 30.87 meters
double R = radius / 30.87 / 3600 * PI / 180;
```

then compute a uniform random point in a circle

```
double a = random() * 2 * PI;
double r = R * sqrt(random());
```

your random point in the disc will be

```
double random_lat = (latitude*PI/180 + r*cos(a))/PI*180;
double random_longitude = (longitude*PI/180 + (r/k)*sin(a))/PI*180;
```