# how to generate a set of random points within a half-circle uniformly in python or R?

Tags: python, r, numpy

I am trying to generate a set of points within a half-circle uniformly.

```
size = 1000
t  = np.random.random(size)*np.pi*2
u  = np.random.random(size) + np.random.random(size)
r = np.where(u > 1, 2 - u, u)
x = r*cos(t)
y = r*sin(t)
coor = (x,y)
for idx, value in enumerate(y):
    if value<0:
        x[idx]=-3
        y[idx]=-3
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (3,3))
plt.scatter(x, y)
```

this piece of code has 2 bugs.

1. the plot has a lot (-3,-3) points to be removed
2. it seems to be inefficient.

the figure shown as below is NOT uniformly, as the points are more of center than others.

[image]

another plot shown as below could be viewed as uniformly.

[image]

any idea to fix the bugs would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you can't get absolute uniformity because of mathematical reasons, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_uniform_distribution, last paragraph in Distribution of the mean: "It follows that they will have zero mean and a variance of 1/2".

Comment: The circle or mean and variance has nothing to do with it? Even uniform points on a square will have a zero mean and some variance? I view uniformity here as how the points are spaced relative to one another within this area.

Comment: thanks for the link, it does not have to be absolute uniformity. relatively uniformity is acceptable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a random point within a circle (uniformly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837572/generate-a-random-point-within-a-circle-uniformly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R:

```
runif_in_semicircle <- function(n, radius=1){
  theta <- runif(n, 0, pi)
  r <- radius * sqrt(runif(n))
  cbind(r*cos(theta), r*sin(theta))
}

sims <- runif_in_semicircle(1000)
plot(sims[,1], sims[,2], asp=1, pch=19)
```

[image]

We can check it works by evaluating an integral.

```
# integrand example
f <- function(x) x[1]^2 + exp(x[2])

set.seed(666)
sims <- runif_in_semicircle(10000)
fsims <- apply(sims, 1, f)
mean(fsims)*pi/2 # approximates the integral of f over the half-disk
# 2.890905
```

Now we numerically evaluate the integral of `f`.

```
library(SphericalCubature)
adaptIntegrateBallPolar(f, n=2, lowerLimit = 0, upperLimit = pi)
# $integral
# [1] 2.880598
```

Comment: thanks! your answer is so helpful! and what does the variable name 'sims' mean, simulator?

Answer (score 5):

You should generate uniformly distributed angles `phi`, and take the `sqrt` of uniformly generated radius `r` (which takes into account that we want to sample uniformly on the *area*, see explanation below), to make sure you sample points uniformly in the half-circle.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample
size = 10000
R = 1
phi = np.random.random(size=size) * np.pi
r = np.sqrt(np.random.random(size=size)) * R

# transform
x = r * np.cos(phi)
y = r * np.sin(phi)

# plot
f = plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
a = f.add_subplot(111)
a.scatter(x, y, marker='.')
a.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image: Uniform samples in a cirlce]

## Explanation

To generate uniformly distributed points on a (half-)circle we have to make sure that each infinitesimal *area* or segment is "hit" with the same probability. We can simply sample `phi` from a uniform random distribution `[0, 1)`, multiplied by `np.pi` (so `[0, pi)`), since all angles should have the same probability to be sampled. But if we sample `r` from a uniform random distribution in `[0, 1)`, we generate too many points at small radia, and not enough at large radia, since the *area* grows like `r**2`. To take that fact into account, we have to bias our sampled radia accordingly, and in this case we can apply the biasing by simply taking the square root (`np.sqrt`), to apply the correct weighting to the sampled radius values, and take into account the larger area of the outer rings.

A much better and more thorough explanation is found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50746409/1170207

## Performance comparison to rejection sampling methods

Since this method is basically an inversion sampling method, we compare its 
performance to a rejection sampling algorithm.

```
import numpy as np
x, y = np.random.random(size=(2,10000))
%timeit r, phi = np.sqrt(x), y
# 19 µs ± 33.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit m = x**2 + y**2 <= 1; xx, yy = x[m], y[m]
# 81.5 µs ± 271 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

With the rejection sampling method we also cannot ensure that we draw a select number of variates, so we have to repeat the process until we have. This cannot be vectorized that nicely, unless we accept to sample too many values, and discard additional ones.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it does not waste any of the points generated.

Comment: It is appreciated if you could add the maths behind to explain why square root is used?

Comment: Considering how slow calculating large numbers of square roots is, I wouldn't be suprised if this is slower than a rejection algorithm.  It is however, much more elegant.

Comment: @DanielF Using `numpy`, the `sqrt` will be a vectorized operation on the whole array. It cannot get much faster than that.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa, You can't do square root faster than that, true.  But a rejection algorithm eliminates the square root step entirely, at the cost of elegance and absolute process stability.

Comment: @DanielF There might be cases where rejection sampling outperforms inversion sampling, but not in this case. There are processor opcodes to calculate sqrt of floats. Nevertheless, I added the comparison to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should generate points in the enclosing rectangle, and remove points which are not in the half-circle

```
# generate about n points in a half-circle with
# given center (x, y) and given radius, and y>0

points <- function(x, y, radius, n) {
    n2 = n * 4 / pi # each point has pi/4 probability to survive

    # make [-1, 1] * [-1, 1] square
    xs = runif(n2, -1, 1)
    ys = runif(n2, 0, 1)  # or just runif(n2)
    points = cbind(xs, ys)

    # keep only points in circle with center (0,0) and radius 1 with y>0
    ind = (xs**2 + ys**2 <= 1) # the condition ys>=0 is obeyed already
    points = points[ind,]

    # move/stretch to given center and radius
    points = points * radius
    points[,1] = points[,1] + x
    points[,2] = points[,2] + y
}

# generate about 1000 points with center(1,1) and radius 3
points = f(1, 1, 3, 1000)

# plot them, making them smaller for better visibility
plot(points, cex=0.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out following in R:

```
size <- 1000
maxRad <- 1 #maximum radius of the half-circle
r <- runif(1000,0,maxRad) #generate random radius
phi <- runif(size,0,pi) #generate angle for polarcoordinates (between 0 and pi since you want a halfcircle)
x <- r*cos(phi) #polarcoordinates
y <- r*sin(phi)
plot(x,y)
```

You can put it in a function

```
halfCircle <- function(size, maxRad) {
 r <- runif(1000,0,maxRad)
 phi <- runif(size,0,1)*pi
 x <- r*cos(phi)
 y <- r*sin(phi)
 plot(x,y)
}
```

and try  out whether it delivers you "more acceptable random" results.

Comment: thanks for your hint, though, it seems to be NOT uniformly

Comment: In my testruns it seems like the points tend to center in the coordinate origin. See the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_uniform_distribution. In the last paragraph in "Distribution of the mean" it is stated that "... they will have zero mean and a variance of 1/2" so you will have something that looks not uniformly, because of mathematical reasons.

Comment: This is not correct. You have to sample `r` according to the *square root* of the uniform distribution.

Answer (score 0):

This method uses `Python`, and a rejection algorithm.

First create uniformly distributed variables in a square. Then reject all points that lie outside the half circle you are interested in. Here I chose the simplest case, but it can be extended to any half circle if you add rotation, scaling and translation of these points.

The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 10000
r = 3  # radius

uniform_square = np.random.uniform(-r,r,(int(2.65*n),2))
radius = np.sqrt(uniform_square[:,0]**2 + uniform_square[:,1]**2)

uniform_circle = uniform_square[radius<=r,:]

uniform_half_circle = uniform_circle[uniform_circle[:,0]>=0,:]

final_points = uniform_half_circle[0:n,:]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1)
axs.scatter(final_points[:,0], final_points[:,1], marker='.')
axs.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
plt.show()
```

Since it uses numpy for all steps, its relatively quick. To get a fixed number of points, generate more than you need initially and downsize the array. Since I started with a perfect square (area=4) and only need a half circle (area = pi/2) we need to generate about 2.6 times as many points as we need in the end.

The for loop in python is not very fast, so try to stick to `numpy` only functions and operations.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean 'uniformly'.

Here is one approach to generate 'uniformly' distributed points along x- and y-axis, but not very efficient

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.random(size) * 2 - 1
y = np.random.random(size)
r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
x[r > 1] = -3
y[r > 1] = -3
plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.show()
```