# plotting random points inside a SVG circle so they are not concentrated at the center

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, plot

I need to plot ***n*** number of points inside a circle of say radius ***R***, randomly. When I try to do it with a random ***theta***, and random distance from the center of the circle, points are concentrated towards the center of the circle and rightfully so. Is there a way to have them spread randomly over the circle as shown below in the image?

**desired output:**

[image]

**Current output:**

[image]

below is the code in D3.js for the current output:

```
while(count){ (count is the number of points to be plotted inside the circle)

        var randAngle = Math.random()*Math.PI*2;
        var randRadius = Math.random()*radius; (radius is the radius of the circle in which I want to plot)
        var randX = cx + randRadius * Math.cos(randAngle);
        var randY = cy + randRadius * Math.sin(randAngle);

    
        parent_group_dns.append('rect')
                        .attr('x', randX)
                        .attr('y', randY)
                        .attr('width', 1.5)
                        .attr('height', 1.5)
                        .attr('fill', 'white')

        count--;
    }
```

is there a way to distribute points not by theta but just by distances?

Comment: There could be something useful for you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837572/generate-a-random-point-within-a-circle-uniformly)

Comment: It's because you're generating the points in polar coordinates. Instead, generate them in Cartesian coordinates and then cull them based on whether or not they're within the circle.

Comment: instead of `var randRadius = Math.random()*radius;`  try `var randRadius = Math.sqrt( ~~(Math.random()*radius*radius));` Also read about [Disk Point Picking](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html)

Comment: @Ouroborus True that. Was struggling to plot in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: @enxaneta WORKED! I understand the reason now. Thanks Much.